# Using ZMQ_XPUB_MANUAL with zeromq.js

Tags: node.js, typescript, zeromq

I am trying to implement a pub/sub broker with ZeroMQ where it is possible to restrict clients from subscribing to prefixes they are not allowed to subscribe to. I found a [tutorial](https://somdoron.com/2014/12/token-pubsub/) that tries to achieve a similar thing using the `ZMQ_XPUB_MANUAL` option. With [zeromq.js](https://github.com/zeromq/zeromq.js) it is possible to set this option:

```
import * as zmq from "zeromq";
// ...
const socket = new zmq.XPublisher({ manual: true });
```

After setting this option I am able to receive the subscription messages by calling `.receive()` on this socket:

```
const [msg] = await socket.receive();
```

But I have no Idea how to accept this subscription. Usally this is done by calling `setSockOpt` with `ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE` but I don't know how to do this with `zeromq.js`.

Is there a way to call `setSockOpt` with `zeromq.js` or is there another way to accept a subscription?

## Edit

I tried user3666197's suggestion to call `setSockOpt` directly, but I am not sure how to do this. Rather than doing that, I took another look in the sources and found this: https://github.com/zeromq/zeromq.js/blob/master/src/native.ts#L617
It seems like `setSockOpt` is exposed to the TypeScript side as protected methods of the `Socket` class. To try this out, I created my own class that inherits XPublisher and exposed an `acceptSubscription` message:

```
class CustomPublisher extends zmq.XPublisher {
  constructor(options?: zmq.SocketOptions<zmq.XPublisher>) {
    super(options);
  }

  public acceptSubscription(subscription: string | null): void {
    // ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE has a value of 6
    // reference:
    // https://github.com/zeromq/libzmq/blob/master/include/zmq.h#L310
    this.setStringOption(6, subscription);
  }
}
```

This works like a charm! But do not forget to strip the first byte of the subscription messages, otherwise your client won't receive any messages since the prefix won't match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Q** : *"Is there a way to call* **`setSockOpt()`** *with `zeromq.js` or is there another way to ***accept a subscription***?"*

So, let me first mention Somdoron to be, out of doubts & for ages, a master of the ZeroMQ tooling.

Next comes the issue. The GitHub-sources, I was able to review atm, seem to me, that permit the **`ZMQ_XPUB`**-Socket-archetypes to process the native API `ZMQ_XPUB_MANUAL` settings ( re-dressed into `manual`-property, an idiomatic shift ), yet present no method (so far visible for me) to actually permit user to meet the native API explicit protocol of:

> ***`ZMQ_XPUB_MANUAL`: change the subscription handling to manual***
> ...
> with manual mode subscription requests are not added to the subscription list. To add subscription the user need to call *`setsockopt()`* with **`ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE`** on `XPUB` socket.
> <sub>/__ from ZeroMQ native API v.4.3.2 documentation __/</sub>

Trying to blind-call the `Socket`-inherited [`.SetSockOpt()` method](https://github.com/zeromq/zeromq.js/blob/e2821f002eebec2428e83614d8b5309388c79342/src/socket.cc#L697) may prove me wrong, yet if successful, it may be a way to inject the `{ ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE | ZMQ_UNSUBSCRIBE }` subscription-management steps into the `XPUB`-instance currently having been switched into the `ZMQ_XPUB_MANUAL`-mode.

Please test it, and if it fails to work via this super-class inherited method, the shortest remedy would be to claim that collision/conceptual-shortcomings directly to the `zeromq.js` maintainers ( it might be a W.I.P. item, deeper in their actual v6+ refactoring backlog, so my fingers are crossed for either case ).